# Merging multiple parameters into the same row in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I got the following table I want to edit with power query (still a beginner).
Every month we got a new row for every parameter (many) for every object.  What I want, is a table with a new row for every every object and every Month with all the parameters listed as columns. The parameters can include numbers, dates, empty values etc.

I hope I could explain my issue well enough.
Thanks for you help!

What I have:

| Parameter | Object | Location | Size | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object A | USA | 4 | Jan 2002 | 180 |
| 1 | Object A | USA | 4 | Feb 2002 | 210 |
| 2 | Object A | USA | 4 | Jan 2002 | 312 |
| 2 | Object A | USA | 4 | Feb 2002 | 140 |
| 1 | Object B | CAN | 6 | Jan 2002 | 164 |
| 1 | Object B | CAN | 6 | Feb 2002 | 130 |
| 2 | Object B | CAN | 6 | Jan 2002 | 95 |
| 2 | Object B | CAN | 6 | Feb 2002 | 122 |

What I want:

| Object | Month | Location | Size | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Object A | Jan 2002 | USA | 4 | 180 | 312 | ... |
| Object A | Feb 2002 | USA | 4 | 210 | 140 | ... |
| Object B | Jan 2002 | CAN | 6 | 164 | 95 | ... |
| Object B | Feb 2002 | CAN | 6 | 130 | 122 | 95 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load data into powerquery with data .. from table/range... [x] headers

click select parameter column

transform .. pivot column

values column:value  [ok]

file ... close and load ...

[image]

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Parameter", Int64.Type}, {"Object", type text}, {"Location", type text}, {"Size", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type datetime}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Parameter", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Parameter", type text}}, "en-US")[Parameter]), "Parameter", "Value", List.Sum)
in   #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!

This is what a tried at first but when I do it, I get the first row value for paramter 1 but null in parameter 2. Then the next row the same date but parameter 1 is null and parameter 2 has its value

and so on. Is there a way to merge them?

Comment: The above  code/method works for the sample data provided.  If you can't use my code / method on your sample data without error, something is wrong.  If the code/method doesn't work on your real data (which differs from the sample data), post either the code you are using or the real data

Comment: Yes, the data unfortunately is sensitive, so I used an abstract example above. Maybe my error is in the previous steps?

The source data looks almost the same but is orderd in the columns: Parameter, Object, Location, Size, and then each month a separate column with the values for all the parameters in their rows.

So my first step was to unpivot those. Maybe here is the error?

Comment: I think I found the (stupid) issue. I was dragging along a additional column which hindered the pivot. Thank you very much!